# The etiquette on necro-ing

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Points:
+ it is my own post with no solving attempts
+ it is a little over a month old; certainly not too much of a necro, but I believe it will age further.
+ I'm unsure when I will put a bounty on it... not any time soon.

My questions following, then:
If it is your own question, unanswered, and is, say... 4 months old (old enough for the attached inactive chat room to have been deleted) and you have not been regularly bumping it, what is an acceptable way to raise it back up? Is it fine to simply edit it? Must you add a bounty? At what age does it start becoming frowned upon to bump it? 1 year?

Comment: I've bumped your question for you, by providing an answer.  :P

Comment: I saw! Time to write a big, beautiful comment in reply-

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, drawing attention to a question is what bounties are for. However, because Puzzling.SE works differently to most other StackExchange sites in that the OP generally already knows the answer, there's another way in which you can bump your question:

### Add a hint!

Not only will this bump your question, it will also (hopefully) make it *slightly* easier for people to finally find the right answer. Generally, hints on Puzzling.SE are hidden in spoiler tags, so that if someone wants to try and solve the puzzle without that help, they're perfectly free to do so, and can then use the hint(s) to help gauge whether their solution is correct or not.

It's considered bad form to add hints or bounties too *early* - wait at least 24 hours, to give people from different time zones a chance to see the question - but after that, you're perfectly welcome to bump a question regardless of how much time has passed, so long as you don't do it too frequently.

(As a final note, if your question has at least one answer but no accepted answer, the Community bot will occasionally bump it to the front page so the answers can be "reviewed". I don't know how often this occurs here on Puzzling.SE, but I've seen it quite frequently on Movies.SE.)

Comment: What if the very beginning domino to the puzzle is, in fact, a riddle that was made to have very low difficulty? I am unsure how to go about adding hints to something that seems like a "gimme". I guess... find another way to describe the answer word?